# Weird undefined method 'all' and collection_select error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, nested-attributes

I've got a form like this (simplified, but you get the idea):

```
<%= form_for(@brand, :html => { :class => "form-horizontal" }) do |f| %>
  <%= f.fields_for :prices do |price| %>
    <%= price.collection_select(:price, :template_id, Template.all, :id, :name) %>
  <% end %>
  <%= f.submit "Save", :class => 'btn btn-primary' %>
<% end %>
```

Which when rendered gives me this error

```
undefined method `all' for ActionView::Template:Class
```

on the `collection_select` line.

`Template.all` works from the controller and the console. If I write a `@templates = Template.all` and use `@templates` in the `collection_select` line then I get this error:

```
undefined method `merge' for :name:Symbol
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: One option would be to expose the templates as an instance variable (or as part of whatever you send to the view layer) and avoid the resolution issue altogether.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it. It was annoyingly simple.

```
<%= price.collection_select(:template_id, @templates, :id, :name) %>
```

Duplication. Eugh.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it by prefixing with two colon. e.g,

```
<%= price.collection_select(:price, :template_id, ::Template.all, :id, :name) %>
```

but I believe, you should avoid using **Template** as model name as it is rails [Action View Template](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Template.html)